# html5 canvas drawing multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code :http://jsfiddle.net/zyR9K/4/

```
var Enemies = {
        x: 25,
        y: 25,
        width: 20,
        height: 30,
        speed: 0.5,
        color: "#000",
        draw: function () {
            canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
            canvas.fillRect(this.x+1, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        },
        update: function () {
            this.y += this.speed
        }
    };
```

I am having a bit of problem to create an algorithm that can produce multiple rectangle that wld look like this :

[image]

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Create a new `Formation` class which contains a 2d array of `Enemies`.

Comment: can u please give me an example

Comment: A game is maybe too ambitious right now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want multiple Enemies (plural), you need an object that manages each of them. I've move your 'enemies' code into 'Enemy', because it represents a single instance. Then created and 'Enemies' object that holds a 'collection' of several 'Enemy' objects, and applies the 'draw' and 'update' functions to each one:

```
var canvas = $("#ContainerCanvas")[0].getContext('2d');
var CanvasWidth = 300;
var CanvasHeight = 300;
var FramePSet = 30;

var frameRunner;

var Enemies = {
    collection: [],
    draw: function () {
        canvas.clearRect(0, 0, CanvasWidth, CanvasHeight);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++){
            this.collection[i].draw();
        }
    },
    update: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++){
            this.collection[i].update();
        }
    }
};

var Enemy = function () {
    var model = {    
        x: 25,
        y: 25,
        width: 20,
        height: 30,
        speed: 0.5,
        color: "#000",
        draw: function () {
            canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
            canvas.fillRect(this.x+1, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        },
        update: function () {
            this.y += this.speed;
        }
    }
    return model;
};

function addEnemy(x, y){
    var nextEnemy = new Enemy();
    nextEnemy.x = x;
    nextEnemy.y = y;
    Enemies.collection.push(nextEnemy);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    addEnemy(25, 25);
    addEnemy(60, 60);
    addEnemy(95, 95);

    frameRunner = setInterval(function () {
         Enemies.update();
         Enemies.draw();
     }, 1000 / FramePSet);     

 });
```

You can just copy and paste this into the js pane of your fiddle. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var enemies = [ ];

var MAX_ROW = 5,
    MAX_COL = 10;

for(var r = 0; r < MAX_ROW; ++r) {
    enemies[r] = [ ];
    switch(r) {
    case 0:
        for(var i = 6; i < 0; --i) {
            enemies[0].push(new Enemy);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        for(var i = 8; i < 0; --i) {
            enemies[1].push(new Enemy);
        }
        break;
    default:
        for(var i = MAX_COL; i < 0; --i) {
            enemies[r].push(new Enemy);
        }
    }
}
```

This ?

Comment: can u pls make a jsfiddle for me

Comment: Yeah i can also code the whole game for you. EDIT : this is sarcasm, just in case...

Comment: You do not give any information about the context or the eventual error messages you get so how do you expect people to help you ? This site isn't made for people to do your job entirely, it's to help people to fix their problem once they have used their brain and tried every possibility they could think of. If that's all you can think of, don't even try to make a video game...

Comment: first when u push to enemies it should be enemies[r].push(new Enemies) second i am trying to loop on enemies array and i did this for(var i=0;i<enemies.length;i++) { enemies[0].draw()} the console gave me that draw is not a function